# example of discontinuous function having direction derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there a function (non piece-wise unlike below) which is discontinuous but has directional derivative at particular point? I have a manual that says the function has directional derivative at $(0,0)$ but is not continuous at $(0,0)$.
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} & \text{ if } x \neq 0\\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}$$

Can anyone give me few examples which is not defined piece wise as above?

Comment: Before I think about $|\cdot |$, does it count as a piece wise function?

Comment: what would that be? could you give me link about |.|

Comment: I mean the absolute value. Of what? Yet to be determined, maybe $|x|$ or $|xy|$..

Comment: I think not .. i just don't want that condition imposed like f(x) = this when x = this or x=that

Comment: It's probably continuous anyway.

Comment: anyway I'll leave the question open!! it's not necessity ... just curious. the only example given in the book is that one above.

Comment: Regarding @did's comment on the answer below: do you require the directional derivative to exist on every direction?

Comment: @GitGud yes!! I am not just looking for partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{xy^2+u^2}{x^2+y^4+u^2}$$

Comment: clever manipulation!!

Comment: @experimentX And I know you can't disallow limits if you would be willing to accept $e^x$ or $\sin x$. :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard "elementary" functions are always continuous where they are defined, so this would be hard to do.  You might try
$$ f(x,y) = \arg( -\exp(i(y-x^2)(2x^2-y))) - (y-x^2)(2x^2-y) $$
where arg is the "principal branch" of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $=0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Comment: OP asked for the function to not bet piece wise defined.

Comment: also I am looking  specifically (if possible) not piecewise functions with conditions

Comment: Since $f(x,x)\to\frac12$ when $x\to0$, some functional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ do not exist.